# how can i parse html in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-http

I am using Flutter and want to parse HTML using parser.dart

```
<div class="weather-item now"><!-- now  -->
   <span class="time">Now</span>
   
    <div class="temp">19.8<span>℃</span>
        <small>(23℃)</small>
    </div>
   
   <table>
       <tr>
           <th><i class="icon01" aria-label="true"></i></th>
           <td>93%</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th><i class="icon02" aria-label="true"></i></th>
           <td>south 2.2km/h</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th><i class="icon03" aria-label="true"></i></th>
           <td>-</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Using,
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

I want to get this data

**Now,19.8,23,93%,south 2.2km/h**

How can I do this?

Comment: are u familiar with XPath? If yes, try this lib: https://pub.dev/packages/xpath

Comment: Probably the easiest method to achieve this is a combination of [.substring()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/substring.html) and [.indexOf()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/indexOf.html).

Answer (score 15):

Since you are using the html package, you can get the desired data like so using some html parsing and string processing (as needed), here is a dart sample, you can use the parseData function as is in your flutter application -

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;

main(List<String> args) {
  parseData();
}

parseData(){
  var document = parse("""
    <div class="weather-item now"><!-- now  -->
   <span class="time">Now</span>
   
    <div class="temp">19.8<span>℃</span>
        <small>(23℃)</small>
    </div>
   
   <table>
       <tr>
           <th><i class="icon01" aria-label="true"></i></th>
           <td>93%</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th><i class="icon02" aria-label="true"></i></th>
           <td>south 2.2km/h</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th><i class="icon03" aria-label="true"></i></th>
           <td>-</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
  """);

  //declaring a list of String to hold all the data.
  List<String> data = [];

  data.add(document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHtml);

  //declaring variable for temp since we will be using it multiple places
  var temp  = document.getElementsByClassName("temp")[0];
  data.add(temp.innerHtml.substring(0, temp.innerHtml.indexOf("<span>")));
  data.add(temp.getElementsByTagName("small")[0].innerHtml.replaceAll(RegExp("[(|)|℃]"), ""));

  //We can also do document.getElementsByTagName("td") but I am just being more specific here.
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("td");

  //Map elememt to its innerHtml,  because we gonna need it. 
  //Iterate over all the table-data and store it in the data list
  rows.map((e) => e.innerHtml).forEach((element) {
    if(element != "-"){
      data.add(element);
    }
  });

  //print the data to console.
  print(data);
  
}
```

Here's the sample output -

```
[Now, 19.8, 23, 93%, south 2.2km/h]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-html-in-dart-with-html-package-cd43c29cc460) would probably be of help. It specifically uses the `html` package parser.

Following the example in the package's readme you can easily obtain a `Document` object. With this object you can obtain specific `Element`s of the DOM with methods like `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName`, and `getElementsByTagName`. From there you can obtain the `innerHtml` of each `Element` that is returned and put together the output string you desire.