# Use website database as a flutter app backend

Tags: flutter

I have just started the flutter journey. I have been asked to develop a mobile app that uses the data of a website instead of its own database(firestore etc.). The website is about car dealing business. It has data about cars and I want to fetch that data into `flutter app` I have no idea how to do it. Is there any `package` or anything else.

Comment: Data of a website mean?  ...You can consume data if API's are available or if not you have to go with data scrapping.

Answer (score 2):

You would combine an [HTTP Client](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) with an [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577610/how-can-i-parse-html-in-flutter), assuming the website itself didn't have a accessible API that readily returns the data you're interested in via JSON.

Comment: Is there any youtube tutorial. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2):

If your website has a firebase backend, then you can use [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/) set of plugins. The google-services.json file should be the same as that of the firebase project used in your website.

If your website has an API you can use the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to make http requests.

Comment: Is there any youtube tutorial. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to build the REST Full API in the website backend using a backend language PHP or Node.js or .Net whatever good for your project, and then use flutter [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) or [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to make requests to the REST API you built, you get back a JSON response then populate the data on your flutter app

Comment: Is there any youtube tutorial. Thank you for responding.

Comment: In this example, you will learn how to get the data from a database and return it as a json https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqEONSbXeSQ

Comment: And in this example you will learn how to call that API you built and use the response to populate the data in your flutter app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEqUx3_KrFo