# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209) Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, http

I am a bit new to flutter and I am getting the message

```
E/flutter (26774): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (26774): <br />
E/flutter (26774): ^
```

In my console when connecting api's for a registration form, this is what I have in my code

```
  Future RegistrationUser() async {
    var APIURL = "http://192.168.1.2/xxxxxxxxx/api/xxxxxxx.php";

    Map mapeddate = {
      'name': _name.text,
      'phone': _phone.text,
      'email': _email.text,
      'pass': _pass1.text,
      'type': "applicant",
    };
    print("JSON DATA: $mapeddate");

    http.Response response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse(APIURL), body: mapeddate);

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print("DATA: ${data}");
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Is there any file with the text shown in your error message (<br/>). Your error seems to point to that opening angular bracket, maybe you added that line somewhere by mistake.

Comment: Your API is returning HTML rather than JSON. You need to find out why and fix it - perhaps your request is malformed.

Comment: Hmmm no I'm sure there's no bracksts anywhere except in the link for the api call itself, and also I' sure that the API is returning JSON format but I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`jsonDecode()` can only parse JSON format. The response from the http request that you've made contains `<br/>` - which is an invalid value in JSON. What you can do here is [parse the HTML String response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62588255/2497859) and fetch the elements - which what I'm guessing that you might need since a sample of the response that you're parsing wasn't provided.